# HTML text inline with image

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to style my footer. In the one block I will need text on the left and text inline with an image (logo name to be used as text) on the right with more text after it. I have successfully done this except on my mobile version the image does not sit inline with the text. Please see used code for .pull-left and .pull-right.

HTML

```
<p class="pull-left">© 2013 
<a href="contact">ENVY BEAUTY</a>
. All rights reserved.
</p>

<p class="pull-right">DESIGNED &amp; MAINTAINED BY 
<a href="http://smugstudios.com.au"><img align="middle" alt="" src="/sites/default/files    /SMUG.FOOTER.STAMP.png" style="width: 50px; height: 30px; float:right; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; " />
</a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.pull-right { float: right; }

.pull-left { float: left; }
```

Comment: you want everything in single line r two lines

Comment: <img src="SMUG.FOOTER.STAMP.png" align="middle"> try this

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or add to style `vertical-align: middle;`

for your footer image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>© 2013 </td>
<td><a href="contact">ENVY BEAUTY</a></td>
<td>. All rights reserved.</td>
<td>DESIGNED &amp; MAINTAINED BY </td>
<td><a href="http://smugstudios.com.au"><img  alt="" src="/sites/default/files    /SMUG.FOOTER.STAMP.png" style="width: 50px; height: 30px; /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables are not recommended for this kind of use due to accessibility issues (also it is a very old method). Check W3C accessibility guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for both elements. I normally use no more than 48%, but use whatever does the job.

```
.pull-right {width: 48%; float: right; }

.pull-left {width: 48%; float: left; }
```

Also, these days it is preferable to avoid inline styles where possible. In your  you have a style attribute. I would include those styles in the style sheet similar to this:

```
.pull-right a img {width: 50px; height: 30px; float:right; padding: 0 5px; margin-top: 0; }
```

I hope this is of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `float: right` from **inline styling** of `img` tag.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKX5Y/2/)**